# How C++ understand both mode of input?

Tags: c++

Please any one can explain that code for me?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int j;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        cin >> j;
        cout << j << endl;
    }
}
```

First scenario
In:
1
2
3
Out:

1
2
3

Second scenario
In: 
1 2 3
Out:
1
2
3

> How C++ understand both mode?

Comment: Explanation could be found at [`operator >>` description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)

Comment: They are the same: numbers separated by whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input is what we call *stream based*.  It is not looking at lines of text at all. When it looks for an `int`, it looks for digit characters, until it finds something that isn't a digit.

In the first example, when the input is

```
1
2
3
```

after it reads each number, it finds a newline character `\n`, which is not a digit, so it signals the end of the number that was just read, and it works just fine.

In the second example, when the input is

```
1 2 3
```

after it reads each number, it finds a space character, which is not a digit, so it signals the end of the number that was just read, and it works just fine.

This is a lot like the way the C++ compiler reads and parses C++ programs.  For example, your program would work the same if you jammed almost all of it all onto one line:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; int main() { int j; for (int i=0; i<3; i++) { cin >> j; cout << j << endl; } }
```

(But preprocessor directives like `#include` are different; those must be alone on their own line.)

Answer (score -1):

this is a simple program that gets the input from console and prints it, and runs for 3 times before executing
cin gets the input and stores it in j
cout prints the output and moves the cursor to newline
case 1:

> > 1
> >     1
> >     2
> >     2
> >     3
> >     3
> >     case 2:
> >     123
> >     123